# Div will not center a banner

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to center a charity banner with code generated from Amazon. My efforts at getting it centered have been unsuccessful. The code from Amazon is:

```
<div id="amznCharityBanner">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
            iFrame.style.display = 'none';
            iFrame.style.border = "none";
            iFrame.width = 310;
            iFrame.height = 256;
            iFrame.setAttribute && iFrame.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
            iFrame.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
            setTimeout(function() {
                var contents = (iFrame.contentWindow) ? iFrame.contentWindow : (iFrame.contentDocument.document) ? iFrame.contentDocument.document : iFrame.contentDocument;
                contents.document.open();
                contents.document.write(decodeURIComponent("%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22amznCharityBannerInner%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsmile.amazon.com%2Fch%2F85-1286688%22%20target%3D%22_blank%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22text%22%20height%3D%22%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22support-wrapper%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22support%22%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%2020px%3B%20line-height%3A%2023px%3B%20margin-top%3A%208.5px%3B%20margin-bottom%3A%208.5px%3B%22%3ESupport%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22charity-name%22%20style%3D%22display%3A%20inline-block%3B%22%3EPath%20to%20Healing%20and%20Crystal%20Gardens%20Sanctuary%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cp%20class%3D%22when-shop%22%3EWhen%20you%20shop%20at%20%3Cb%3Esmile.amazon.com%2C%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%20class%3D%22donates%22%3EAmazon%20donates.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23amznCharityBannerInner%7Bbackground-image%3Aurl(https%3A%2F%2Fm.media-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fx-locale%2Fpaladin%2Fcharitycentral%2Fbanner-background-image._CB485922134_.png)%3Bwidth%3A300px%3Bheight%3A250px%3Bposition%3Arelative%7D%23amznCharityBannerInner%20a%7Bdisplay%3Ablock%3Bwidth%3A100%25%3Bheight%3A100%25%3Bposition%3Arelative%3Bcolor%3A%23000%3Btext-decoration%3Anone%7D.text%7Bposition%3Aabsolute%3Btop%3A20px%3Bleft%3A15px%3Bright%3A15px%3Bbottom%3A100px%7D.support-wrapper%7Boverflow%3Ahidden%3Bmax-height%3A86px%7D.support%7Bfont-family%3AArial%2Csans%3Bfont-weight%3A700%3Bline-height%3A28px%3Bfont-size%3A25px%3Bcolor%3A%23333%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3Bbackground%3A0%200%7D.when-shop%7Bfont-family%3AArial%2Csans%3Bfont-size%3A15px%3Bfont-weight%3A400%3Bline-height%3A25px%3Bcolor%3A%23333%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3Bbackground%3A0%200%7D.donates%7Bfont-family%3AArial%2Csans%3Bfont-size%3A15px%3Bfont-weight%3A400%3Bline-height%3A21px%3Bcolor%3A%23333%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3Bbackground%3A0%200%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E"));
                contents.document.close();
                iFrame.style.display = 'block';
            });
            document.getElementById('amznCharityBanner').appendChild(iFrame);
        })();
    </script>
</div>
```

I have tried within the div tag:

```
style="margin: 0 auto"
```

and

```
style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto"
```

I have also tried centering a div surrounding the code to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you centering the div in?  You should show the html/css for the parent element.  For example, if this div is a child of a div that only takes up 20% of the left side of the page, it won't be centered on the page.

Comment: It is free standing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the auto margin to the iframe.

You could add:

```
iFrame.style.margin = "0 auto";
```

after `iFrame.style.border = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

```
 .text-example { display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;flex-direction: column; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 10% 0; min-height: 200px; background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, .3); align-items: center; }


I have given some idea check it I hope it's work for you good luck
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div id="amznCharityBanner">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
var iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
 iFrame.style.display = 'none';
 iFrame.style.border = "none";
 iFrame.width = 310;
iFrame.style.margin="0px auto";
 iFrame.height = 256;
 iFrame.setAttribute && iFrame.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no'); 
iFrame.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
 setTimeout(function () { 
var contents = (iFrame.contentWindow) ? 
iFrame.contentWindow : 
 (iFrame.contentDocument.document) ? 
iFrame.contentDocument.document :
 iFrame.contentDocument;
 contents.document.open();
 contents.document.write(decodeURIComponent("%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22amznCharityBannerInner%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsmile.amazon.com%2Fch%2F85-1286688%22%20target%3D%22_blank%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22text%22%20height%3D%22%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22support-wrapper%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22support%22%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%2020px%3B%20line-height%3A%2023px%3B%20margin-top%3A%208.5px%3B%20margin-bottom%3A%208.5px%3B%22%3ESupport%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22charity-name%22%20style%3D%22display%3A%20inline-block%3B%22%3EPath%20to%20Healing%20and%20Crystal%20Gardens%20Sanctuary%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cp%20class%3D%22when-shop%22%3EWhen%20you%20shop%20at%20%3Cb%3Esmile.amazon.com%2C%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%20class%3D%22donates%22%3EAmazon%20donates.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23amznCharityBannerInner%7Bbackground-image%3Aurl(https%3A%2F%2Fm.media-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fx-locale%2Fpaladin%2Fcharitycentral%2Fbanner-background-image._CB485922134_.png)%3Bwidth%3A300px%3Bheight%3A250px%3Bposition%3Arelative%7D%23amznCharityBannerInner%20a%7Bdisplay%3Ablock%3Bwidth%3A100%25%3Bheight%3A100%25%3Bposition%3Arelative%3Bcolor%3A%23000%3Btext-decoration%3Anone%7D.text%7Bposition%3Aabsolute%3Btop%3A20px%3Bleft%3A15px%3Bright%3A15px%3Bbottom%3A100px%7D.support-wrapper%7Boverflow%3Ahidden%3Bmax-height%3A86px%7D.support%7Bfont-family%3AArial%2Csans%3Bfont-weight%3A700%3Bline-height%3A28px%3Bfont-size%3A25px%3Bcolor%3A%23333%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3Bbackground%3A0%200%7D.when-shop%7Bfont-family%3AArial%2Csans%3Bfont-size%3A15px%3Bfont-weight%3A400%3Bline-height%3A25px%3Bcolor%3A%23333%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3Bbackground%3A0%200%7D.donates%7Bfont-family%3AArial%2Csans%3Bfont-size%3A15px%3Bfont-weight%3A400%3Bline-height%3A21px%3Bcolor%3A%23333%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bmargin%3A0%3Bpadding%3A0%3Bbackground%3A0%200%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E")); contents.document.close();
 iFrame.style.display = 'block'; }); 
document.getElementById('amznCharityBanner').appendChild(iFrame);
 })(); 
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: add iFrame.style.margin="0px auto" to your iFrame component. I have already added that above but it is looking ugly .